changes in the settings theme are not immediately reflected in the current UI
I use the following code to implement multi them in my app, when I changed the them and select a new one, the whole app is changed correctly, except the current view which not changed, what the required modification to make the current view response to the changing in them:

 var selectedTheme = 'system'.obs;

 List<String> themes = ['system', 'light', 'dark'];

 void changeTheme(String theme) {
   selectedTheme.value = theme;
   ThemeMode themeMode;
   switch (theme) {
     case 'system':
       themeMode = ThemeMode.system;
       break;
     case 'light':
       themeMode = ThemeMode.light;
       break;
     case 'dark':
       themeMode = ThemeMode.dark;
       break;
     default:
       themeMode = ThemeMode.system;
   }
   Get.changeThemeMode(themeMode);
   saveSelectedTheme(theme);
 }

 ThemeMode getThemeMode() {
   switch (selectedTheme.value) {
     case 'light':
       return ThemeMode.light;
     case 'dark':
       return ThemeMode.dark;
     default:
       return ThemeMode.system;
      }
    }
   .....
   }

Below at the SettingsView I call the changeTheme function to change them:
 class SettingsView extends StatelessWidget {
 final SettingsController controller = Get.put(SettingsController());
 SettingsView({super.key});
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
     backgroundColor: Get.isDarkMode
         ? AppTheme.darkBackgroundColor
         : AppTheme.lightBackgroundColor,
     appBar:CustomAppBar(title:  'settings'.tr),
     body: Padding(
       padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
       child: Column(
         children: [
           ListTile(
             title: Text(
               'app_theme'.tr,
               style: const TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Alexandria'),
             ),
             subtitle: Obx(
                   () => Text(
                 controller.selectedTheme.value,
                 style: const TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Alexandria'),
               ),
             ),
             leading: const Icon(Icons.brightness_6),
             trailing: DropdownButton<String>(
               value: controller.selectedTheme.value,
               items: controller.themes.map((theme) {
                 return DropdownMenuItem(
                   value: theme,
                   child: Text(
                     theme,
                     style: const TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Alexandria'),
                   ),
                 );
               }).toList(),
               onChanged: (value) {
                 if (value != null) {
                   controller.changeTheme(value);
                 }
               },
             ),
           ),


can you please try again by converting the stateless widget into stateful widget

It dosn't work.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

While I cannot identify your problem by looking at the code provided, I have several pieces of advice.

Create a project using get_cli. This way you will be sure that everything is set up properly.
You do not need a GetXConroller to update the mode. Just call Get.changeThemeMode from the select handler.

